# update two mysql tables with data from each

Tags: php, mysql

Originally I had one mysql video table that is shown to a user in a simple html table. They could select one or more checkboxes (`$video_list`) to mark for deletion with a query (doesn't actually delete, but updates record)

```
//store all video names in array
    foreach ($video_list as $element) {
        $deleteNames[] = $db->quote($element);
    }

//create nice comma separated list for query
$deleteNames = implode(',', $deleteNames);

// query used
$query_delete_video = sprintf('UPDATE `videos` SET deleted_datetime=NOW() WHERE `video_name` IN (%s)', $deleteNames);
```

Now the problem is that this html table now has images as well, not just videos. These images are in a separate table called `images`. A user can select a number of videos or images at the same time or just videos or just images all for deletion.

So now the list `$deleteNames` has potentially a mix of videos and image names.

The query for images alone would look like:

```
$query_delete_image = sprintf('UPDATE `images` SET deleted_datetime=NOW() WHERE `image_name` IN (%s)', $deleteNames);
```

Same thing just in a different table and different column name. The only way I can think of having these two queries is that I separate `$deleteNames` into images and videos maybe by parsing the extension or something else.

Then I can run the query for each table. Is there a better way to tackle this, maybe in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do this in one query. I do not think you get any significant advantage by this. I think all you want to do is a clean, more efficient query. Having two queries to delete lists from two tables is not a bad design.

This relevant question might help you a little bit. [MySql update two tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765490/mysql-update-two-tables-at-once)

Update query runs against a single table so I dont think you can update two tables in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full table structure, so this may or may not work.  But... why not use a table called "media" (or whatever you want), and add a "type" column which is indexed.  You can then have your form have a checkboxes with the values of an auto increment id, and they would all be valid for that table.  You could do the update query for both video/images with a single query, and your selects will just need an additional condition in WHERE, for "type='video'" or "type='image'"

Comment: Yes, I think a better structure would help, but I'm stuck with what I've got. Thanks.