# Laravel - combining multiple queries to update two table's data using single query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

In one of my `Laravel` project, I have to update two table's data within a same scope of a function. At first query, I am trying to update data of a table using following query -

```
        DB::table('parameters')
        ->where($where)
        ->update($data);
```

In second and third query I am adding and subtracting two column's of another table -

```
DB::table('categories')
            ->where(['id' => $data['category_id']])
            ->increment('parameters');

DB::table('categories')
            ->where(['id' => $previous_category_id])
            ->decrement('parameters');
```

Everything is  working fine. But, now I want to do all these operations within one query execution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this there is no way to do this with *one* query.

What you are basically doing with the `DB:table` facade is runnig a MySQL UPDATE statement like:
`UPDATE <table_name> SET <field_name>=<value> WHERE condition`

As you can see an UPDATE query is pointed to exactly *one* table, not more. So for updating multiple tables you need to run multiple UPDATE queries.

Comment: Okay, I thought about that. I saw a problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765490/mysql-update-two-tables-at-once

and thinking is there any way to do that, without using query builder.