# Update two MySQL Databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have read on several SO threads that it is possible to update two databases using an `INNER JOIN` update query but I am unable to get it to work, it just throws error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'category' in field list is ambiguous' in C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php:79 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php(79): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php on line 79

**LINE 79:** `$result = $stmt->execute($prepare);`

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : null;
    $manufactuer = isset($_POST['manufactuer']) ? $_POST['manufactuer'] : null;
    $model = isset($_POST['model']) ? $_POST['model'] : null;
    $serial = isset($_POST['serial']) ? $_POST['serial'] : null;
    $itemcondition = isset($_POST['itemcondition']) ? $_POST['itemcondition'] : null;
    $locationb = isset($_POST['locationb']) ? $_POST['locationb'] : null;
    $locationr = isset($_POST['locationr']) ? $_POST['locationr'] : null;
    $comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : null;
    $purchased = isset($_POST['purchased']) ? $_POST['purchased'] : null;
    $retired = isset($_POST['retired']) ? $_POST['retired'] : null;
    $stolen = isset($_POST['stolen']) ? $_POST['stolen'] : null;

    $sql_part = array();
    $prepare = array();
    if ($category){
        $sql_part[] = 'category = :category';
        $prepare[':category'] = $category;
    }
    if($manufactuer){
        $sql_part[] = 'manufactuer = :manufactuer';
        $prepare[':manufactuer'] = $manufactuer;
    }
    if($model){
        $sql_part[] = 'model = :model';
        $prepare[':model'] = $model;
    }
    if($serial){
        $sql_part[] = 'serial = :serial';
        $prepare[':serial'] = $serial;
    }
    if($itemcondition){
        $sql_part[] = 'itemcondition = :itemcondition';
        $prepare[':itemcondition'] = $itemcondition;
    }
    if($locationb){
        $sql_part[] = 'locationb = :locationb';
        $prepare[':locationb'] = $locationb;
    }
    if($locationr){
        $sql_part[] = 'locationr = :locationr';
        $prepare[':locationr'] = $locationr;
    }
    if($comments){
        $sql_part[] = 'comments = :comments';
        $prepare[':comments'] = $comments;
    }
    if($purchased){
        $sql_part[] = 'purchased = :purchased';
        $prepare[':purchased'] = $purchased;
    }
    if($retired){
        $sql_part[] = 'retired = :retired';
        $prepare[':retired'] = $retired;
    }
    if($stolen){
        $sql_part[] = 'stolen = :stolen';
        $prepare[':stolen'] = $stolen;
    }
    $prepare[':barcode'] = $barcode;

    if(count($sql_part)){
        $sql = 'UPDATE assets a INNER JOIN assets_history b ON (a.barcode = b.barcode) SET ';
        $sql .= implode(', ', $sql_part);
        $sql .= ' WHERE a.barcode = :barcode AND b.barcode = :barcode';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if($stmt){
            $result = $stmt->execute($prepare);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            header('Location: ./usearch.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the database structure, in case it's needed:

```
  `barcode` int(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
  `category` text NOT NULL
  `manufactuer` text NOT NULL
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  `serial` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  `itemcondition` text NOT NULL
  `locationb` text NOT NULL
  `locationr` text NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  `purchased` varchar(30) NOT NULL
  `retired` varchar(30) NOT NULL
  `stolen` varchar(30) NOT NULL
```

Is there a better way to do it or am I missing something stupid.

I've also just seen the possibility of relating the two table's columns in PHPMyAdmin but not tried yet.  The two tables are identical, one will just keep all updates made to records.

I've had no luck with these articles, one of them is the basis of my code.

[MySQL UPDATE syntax with multiple tables using WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037883/mysql-update-syntax-with-multiple-tables-using-where-clause)

[MySql update two tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765490/mysql-update-two-tables-at-once)

[How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

[MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table name` with column `category` its present in both table

```
if ($category){
    $sql_part[] = 'assets.category = :category';
    $prepare[':category'] = $category;
}
```

Comment: Please confirm the line no 79 in update.php & echo the $sql to debug purpose & post the sql here

Comment: Both tables have the same fields.  Changing all the SQL Parts to `assets.` solves the issue but it only updates the `assets` table and not `assets_history` table

Comment: You should also add for `assets_history` along with `assets`

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show best practice please?

Comment: `if ($category){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.category = :category';
        $sql_part[] = "b.category = :category";
        $prepare[':category'] = $category;
    }` ?

Comment: Thank you, the code I posted in the above comment did the trick.  Please edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me 'assets' & 'assets_history' both has 'category' field.
So update  your code: (replace  by your exact table_name either 'assets' or 'assets_history'

```
if ($category){
        $sql_part[] = '<TABLE_NAME>.category = :category';
        $prepare[':category'] = $category;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the table name or its alias to avoid confusion like this

```
if ($category){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.category = :category';
        $prepare[':category'] = $category;
    }
    if($manufactuer){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.manufactuer = :manufactuer';
        $prepare[':manufactuer'] = $manufactuer;
    }
    if($model){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.model = :model';
        $prepare[':model'] = $model;
    }
    if($serial){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.serial = :serial';
        $prepare[':serial'] = $serial;
    }
    if($itemcondition){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.itemcondition = :itemcondition';
        $prepare[':itemcondition'] = $itemcondition;
    }
    if($locationb){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.locationb = :locationb';
        $prepare[':locationb'] = $locationb;
    }
    if($locationr){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.locationr = :locationr';
        $prepare[':locationr'] = $locationr;
    }
    if($comments){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.comments = :comments';
        $prepare[':comments'] = $comments;
    }
    if($purchased){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.purchased = :purchased';
        $prepare[':purchased'] = $purchased;
    }
    if($retired){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.retired = :retired';
        $prepare[':retired'] = $retired;
    }
    if($stolen){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.stolen = :stolen';
        $prepare[':stolen'] = $stolen;
    }
    $prepare[':barcode'] = $barcode;
```

EDIT:
You can also do this to update all the columns

```
$columns = array('category','manufactuer','model','serial','itemcondition','locationb','locationr','comments','purchased','retired','stolen');
$sql_part = array();
foreach($columns as $column){
        $sql_part[] = 'a.'.$column.' = :'.$column;
        $sql_part[] = 'b.'.$column.' = :'.$column;
        $prepare[':'.$column] = '$'.$column;

}
```

This will save you several lines of code

Comment: Would that also need to be done for b.etc.. on them all too?  As the tables are identical

Comment: sorry forgot to also say that I had done this and it removes the error stated in the question but only updates `assets` and not `assets_history`.