# MySQL multitable update with repeated rows

Tags: mysql, sql, multicol

Let's suppose the following "template" query:

```
update ticket inner join event on ticket.event = event.id
   seat.any_field = <expr1>,
   event.any_field = event.any_field + <expr2>
where event.id = <eid> and seat.another_field = <expr3>
```

Suppose that query affects `n` seats (the `<expr3>` expression selects `n` seats), and `<eid>` is of course any `event` identifier. So, all the selected tickets come from the same event.

Of course, if `n` is for example, `7`, that query will have `7` rows, and each row refering to the same event.

In that situation, will the `set event.any_field = event.any_field + <expr2>` clause be executed `n` times (once for each row), or just one (because only one event is selected after all)?

In the former case (it is executed `n` times), it's possible to execute it only once? (appart from doing two different queries, of course).

Comment: You can't use `limit` in an `update` query with a `join`.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8765573/4421474